# RegEx in java, non-capturing group

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have code below:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(?:h)?o");
Matcher m = pt.matcher("hours 123");
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

And the result is

```
ho
```

Here in regex I have a non-capturing `group (?:h)`. Why is this group included in the final results? I just want to get "o" instead.

Comment: fyi, a non-capturing group is still part of the whole match, it is just not included in the group matches.

Comment: finally i get it. (?:h) is included in result.it just indicates that i can not use $1, it is made for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your positive lookbehind is wrong. It should be this:

```
(?<=h)o
```

For more info, you can read this page:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: That is, _if_ the OP wanted to do a lookbehind. Nothing in the OP's question indicates that the OP wanted to do so.

Answer (score 2):

`group(0)` is the whole match. You need to

```
Pattern.compile("(?:h)?(o)");
```

and use `m.group(1)`

Comment: This is the actual answer to the OP's question, even if the other answer was OP's preferred solution.